# GWT URLs with # doesn't work with IE7

Tags: ajax, gwt, internet-explorer-7

There seem to be a know issue with IE which doesn't respond to URLs that have # sign in them.
See for example: https://mootools.lighthouseapp.com/projects/2706/tickets/638-request-fails-when-url-has-hash-in-ie7

As we use # quite frequently in out GWT based application we are lacking support for IE7 users who want to browse the site.

Is there any known workaround for GWT other than modifying the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally figured out what the problem is. 
Our gwt application is sitting as an iframe inside another HTML file so setting the gwt history support

```
<iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
```

has to be done in the outer HTML rather than the gwt one.
This gwt script was meant to support browsers such as IE6 and IE7 which don't have the onhashchange event implemented.

Answer (score 0):

History works perfectly well in our GWT app in all IE versions...

That ticket was about XMLHttpRequest, so do not use hashes in your xmlhttprequests. It has nothing to do with GWT.

Comment: I agree which is why I tagged it with ajax as well but since we are using GWT I thought there might be a workaround that GWT can offer other than modifying the URL. Does this mean that you don't use "#" at all in your GWT app?

Comment: And if you don't use "#" in your URLs then how do you make your site comply with Google's Ajax Crawling scheme to make it crawleble as they require #! in the URLs? http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html. Plus, websites such as facebook seem to have # in their URLs and it seem to be working under IE7

Comment: "Location" part of an URL (the one after #) is not passed to server when you type URL in your browser. Locations (or hashes, if you like) are strictly for client-side. Your server should not have to accept # in request URLs. That's why there is no reason why you should pass it along with XmlHttpRequest. If you want to pass some parameters, use a regular query string instead, like this: ?param1=value1&...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the problem described in the supplied link is related with URLs that you query with XMLHttpRequest. In GWT application # can appear in ordinary GET request (when you are opening the page, that is when you are starting your GWT application). When GWT does XMLHttpRequest request, it uses URLs similar to:

http://yourserver.com/context/com.yourcompany.SomeModule/someService

There is no # in it, so if you have any problems, they are not related with this issue.